# .NET postback makes other browsers load IE conditional comments

Tags: asp.net, .net, browser, webforms, conditional-comments

Here is my standard conditional comments to give IE hacks to IE8 and below only. It works on initial load.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="Styles/IE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
```

When there is a postback, Chrome 21.0.1180.60 m suddenly loads it! What is going on?

**Update:**

I Confirmed that this happens in Firefox and Opera as well. I am wondering if somehow .NET scrapes the source for CSS includes without regard to conditional comments and puts them in the viewstate, which somehow includes the CSS file on postback? Does that even make sense? What else could be happening here?

**Update 2:**

This is weird. The conditional comments only load CSS, (not plaintext, html, or javascript) and only if in the header. Firefox, Opera, and IE will load any number of conditional comments (regardless of which browser they target), but Chrome will only load the first one. Thus:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link href="Styles/IE.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <style>#test{border:dashed 1px red;</style>
    <script>alert("seven");</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <style>#test{border:dashed 1px blue;</style>
    <script>alert("eight");</script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <style>#test{border:dashed 1px green;</style>
    <script>alert("nine");</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Will load the `IE.css` in all browsers on postback, and IE, Opera and Firefox will load the CSS for IE 7, 8 and 9, resulting in a green border on `#test`. Chrome doesn't give `#test` any border. No javascript alerts will happen.

Comment: Do you have the a live URL for the site where this is occurring?

Comment: It's on a local dev environment running on IIS Express.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RadControls is grabbing the conditional stylesheet only when in the header...as far as I can tell from their documentation ( http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-conditional-comments.html ), it says: "Unfortunately we have not found a feasible way to check for those [referring to the conditional stylesheets] and we cannot easily fix this problem.", so they just provided a couple workarounds, 1 option being to place the conditional comments in the body. So, to answer your question, the developers know this is a bug and will hopefully fix soon...

Comment: Wow that sucks. This is why I like open source stuff, you never get that 'yeah, it's a bug, no we don't know when/if we'll fix it.'

Answer (score 1):

Just to rule out anything obvious, but you're not using the IE Tab Chrome extension, are you?
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hehijbfgiekmjfkfjpbkbammjbdenadd

Comment: If you're using RadControls, you might want to take a look at this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajax-conditional-comments.html  Looks like moving the conditional stylesheet into the body fixes the issue...

Comment: @ews2001 Yeah, I am using RadControls, that's exactly what's happening. It looks like your link is saying that the RadAjaxManager somehow grabs them when they're in the header? Why? Post this as an answer and I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I'd attack this by using [HeadJS](http://headjs.com/) or another js library instead of conditional stylesheets. It's a pretty nifty library that has browser detection, along with a bunch of other things.

```
/ older than IE9 /
.lt-ie9 .box { padding: 10px; }

/ CSS fixes for IE6 /
.ie6 ul  { list-style: none; }
```